# showing select when make a change on other select ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, select

i have a code and i do not know what is my problem with it.
i am trying to open another select from other select,and get the old select value in the new select option, but i can not do that and i do not know why.
this is my code, and my page i wrote the code in it called mekha.php :

```
  <html>
  <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("makhfe").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","mekha.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["q"]))
{
echo $_GET["q"];
}
?>
<select id="firstselect" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<select style="display:none;" id="makhfe">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2"><?=intval($_GET["q"])?></option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 $("#firstselect").change(function() {
    value = $("#firstselect").val();
    data = {"value": value };
    $.post("server_ajax_link.php", data)
       .done(function(data) {
         new_data = data.new_value_from_server;
     });

    $("#makhfe").show();
    $("#makhfe[value='2']").text(new_data );
});
```

For more simple examples you could check out the documentation here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: thanks... but i need to change php variable and use it in sql query..i did the change on the select option just to see if it is working...but actually i need to change a php variable

Comment: You could do in the serve side file then query you want, then work with result that your get back through ajax. If these is not what you looking for please explain more.

Comment: i need when i change the first select...to get his value in post or get via ajax..

Comment: That what the code does.
value = $("#firstselect").val();    data = {"value": value }; these lines take the value from the first selece. these lines $.post("server_ajax_link.php", data)
       .done(function(data) {
         new_data = data.new_value_from_server;
     });  Sends it to server and gets  whatever you want from the server. these lines $("#makhfe").show();
    $("#makhfe[value='2']").text(new_data ); placing the new data from the server in the second select. what did i miss?

Comment: Could you provide a link and the server side script